# What are the best way to use a List on RuntimeExceptions?

Tags: java, exception, serialization, runtimeexception

I have an exception that extends a `RuntimeException`, and I have an attribute `List`.

```
public class ExperterBadRequestException extends RuntimeException {

private final List<String> errors;
```

Automatic evaluation tools like Sonar throw a critical error: The problem is that `RuntimeExceptions` are `Serializable`, and `List` is an interface don't.

So what should I do? Change from List to an `ArrayList` (don't believe that), should not use Lists in this case? make an `writeObject` and `readObject` for it? Or maybe this warning don't make sense?

Comment: do you serialize the exception at all?

Comment: The only thing that matters is whether the *actual* type is serializable, and that only matters if you ever serialize the exception, which is actually rare.

Comment: Not explicitly, I'm not sure about the use of it on log traces or other uses on thrown exceptions really. In fact I'm worried about best practices on that.

Comment: What makes you think there is any problem anywhere? Have you experienced some program failure? If so, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that RuntimeExceptions are Serializable, and List is an interface don't.

No, that isn't a problem. As long as it's initialised to a serializable implementation of `List,` such as any of those in the JDK, this is no problem at all.

> So what should I do?

Nothing.

> Change from List to an ArrayList (don't believe that)

Unnecessary.

> should not use Lists in this case?

No, why?

> make an writeObject and readObject for it?

Unnecessary.

If you are experiencing a problem, you haven't stated what it actually is.

Comment: You are correct of course. +1 and I deleted my answer.

Comment: The auto evaluation of tools like Sonar send a critical error on that, but I took the point.

Comment: I will complete my question to make sense about it.